# Invalid multibulk length In redis

Tags: redis, jedis

I am getting the following exceptions while accessing Redis. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

> ERR Protocol error: invalid multibulk length; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: ERR Protocol error: invalid multibulk length

Comment: Please include [mcve] in your question

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/201

Answer (score 3):

the length of args of the API command MSET can't be bigger than **1024 * 1024**, so the length of the array `KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>[]` values cant be bigger than **524288**, so I limit it to **524287**, then it works.

LINK: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/201